# Installation Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install Ubuntu on my older Acer notebook using a DVD disc after trying Zorin for a bit. For some reason I always receive a failed install when nearly to the end of the install. Yet I can "Try Ubuntu" without a problem. I've also tried this install using a USB with the same result. When the laptop is rebooted, all I get is a black screen with a blinking prompt in the upper left.

Comment: Give us more datails about the laptop, cpu, ram

Comment: Also, which version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

I think so you are having some problem with grub installation.While installing ubuntu try to connect to internet.SO that it can able to download needed files while installing for your hardware.